# Finding unknown point (x,y) using vectors and dot product

Tags: vectors

Given 4 points:
A(6,4)
B(12,8)
C(7,9)
D(1,5)
[image]

These 4 point makes a parallelogram. The problem I am trying to solve is: From point C I draw a line down to the line between A and B which is perpendicular to the line between A and B. This gives me a point E on the line AB. I am trying to find the coordinates for this point E

Since the angle at point E is 90 degrees, I am thinking I can use the dot product
Vector EC dotted with vector EB = 0
Vector EC is [7-x,9-y] and vector EB is [12-x,8-y]
Dot these two vectors: [7-x,9-y] and [12-x,8-y]=0 i get:
(7-x)(12-x)+(9-y)(8-y)=0
I have two unknowns x and y. I need another equation. Anyway, I get quadratic equations in x and y and thinking that I am not thinking correct. I am stuck

Comment: Hint: $\,EC \perp AB\,$ gives a linear equation, then the second one is that $\,E\,$ lies on $\,AB\,$.

Comment: I can easily find the point E by finding the equations for these two straight lines using standard methods. AB is y= (2/3)x and EC is y=-1.5x+19.5. Setting these equal and solve for x gives 9. Putting x=9 into one of them gives y=6. So the point E is (9,6). However, the problems state that I use vectors to find the point E. which to me seems unnecessary complex. However, I would like to learn how to user vectors to find the point E. And here I am stuck. probably over thinking the problem

Comment: You can do it with vectors, of course. But if you write $\,(7-x,9-y) \cdot (12-6,8-4)=0\,$ instead of $\,(7-x,9-y) \cdot (12-x,8-y)=0\,$ you get a linear equation instead of a quadratic one. Then you can do something similar for the second condition of collinearity.

Comment: Thanks, I made it using your suggestion. Very helpfull